# different ways of disabling password logins on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, users

What is the difference between:

`pw lock <user>`

and

`pw mod user <user> -w no`

They both accomplish the same thing: disabling password-based logins, but why would I pick one way over the other?

Answer (score 4):

From the [pw(8) manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pw(8)) (this is always where you should look first when you have a question about a program! `man pw`)

> ```
> USER LOCKING
>      The pw utility supports a simple password locking mechanism for users; it
>      works by prepending the string `*LOCKED*' to the beginning   of the pass-
>      word field   in master.passwd to prevent successful authentication.
>
>      The lock and unlock commands take a user name or uid of the account to
>      lock or unlock, respectively.  The   -V, -C, and -q options as described
>      above are accepted   by these commands.
> ```

vs.

(section about `usermod`, which I presume you meant with `mod user`)

> ```
>  -w   method     The -w option selects the default method used to set pass-
>      words for newly created user accounts.  method is one of:
>
>        no  disable login on newly created accounts
>        yes     force the password to be the account name
>        none    force a blank password
>        random  generate a random password
>
>      The `random' or `no' methods are the most secure; in the
>      former case, pw generates a password and prints it to std-
>      out, which is suitable when users are issued passwords
>      rather than being allowed to select their own (possibly
>      poorly chosen) password.  The `no' method requires that the
>      superuser use passwd(1) to render the account accessible
>      with a password.
> ```

So, `lock` can be reverted with an `unlock`, `usermod <user> -w no` will *delete* the password and an admin will need to set a *new* one, and tell it the user (which might include sending it over an untrusted medium).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the man page and I was aware of the fact that both ways resulted in a different change in the password file. Maybe I should have been more specific in my question: why would I choose one way over the other. Judging from your answer, I guess I would choose "lock" if want to undo the operation and leave the original password intact, correct?

Comment: Also, the term "locked" would suggest it would disallow all methods of login (including ssh key-based auth), but this doesn't seem to be the case if both methods only change the password field. This is the kind of information which is not clear from the man page.

Comment: well "lock" seems to block ssh access as well, this was not clear from the man page.

Comment: you're right on both accounts! If you want to be able to undo the password change, you'd want to `lock`. I'm not deep enough into how FreeBSD actually manages this, but *this might be something your OS has no influence on*:

Comment: sshd runs as root so it can spawn a program (e.g. a shell) as any user (has to do that, right). Whether or not sshd cares about what is in some password file is up to sshd – as long as the uid exists, it will be able to set it and `exec` than new program. FreeBSD can't stop it from that. Now, sshd probably is clever and will recognize a user with a `*LOCKED*` (probably `getspnam` returns something "special")  password *shouldn't be able to log in via SSH*, and blocks that.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, and based on the feedback in the comments and the man page, These are my results:

- "lock" keeps the original password field, and adds *LOCKED* to the password field, which allows to "undo" the action and keep the original password intact. However, a locked user is unable to login via SSH via key-based authentication.
- The "-w no" options, sets the password field to "*" thereby disabling any form of password-based login. However this does NOT block SSH-based access using key-based authentication!